# How to do rest APi with wordpress

Tags: plugins, rest-api

I want to use rest Api with my website i have `WP REST API` plugin installed but i don't want to get just posts my website is a listing website all my listings are done with this plugin `Listing Builder Plugin`. Is there a way i can GET and POST listings

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should re-submit permalink to enable rest api in your wordpress. your rest api url is:
http://your-site.com/wp-json/

And you can register new endpoind with bellow code:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v1', '/author/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
    ) );
} );
```

Comment: This example only shows a GET endpoint without the handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all this information in the docs at http://v2.wp-api.org. If you're going to POST new data then you need to be authenticated. http://v2.wp-api.org/guide/authentication/